# Creating a different array related to different times a loop happens php

Tags: php, arrays

there. I'm having a problem with creating arrays in certain conditions in php, i'll try to explain. Here's my code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $tamanho_array_afundamento; $i++) {
    if ($array_afundamento[$i] - $array_afundamento[$i - 1] > 1) {
        $a = $array_afundamento[$i - 1];

        $con->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS afunda_$a
                     SELECT (L1_forma_tensao_max + L1_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L1_forma_tensao, (L2_forma_tensao_max + L2_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L2_forma_tensao, (L3_forma_tensao_max + L3_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L3_forma_tensao
                     FROM afundamento
                     WHERE id > $prevNum AND id < $a');

        $tabelas_intervalos_afunda1 = ($con->query("SELECT * FROM afunda_$a");

        while ($row = $tabelas_intervalos_afunda->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
            $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
            $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
        }
        $prevNum = $a;
    }
}
```

So as u can see, i have an if statement in a for loop, what i'm wishing to do is to create
one set of:

```
{
    $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
    $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
    $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
    }
```

every time the if statement is runned. I was trying replacing this in the original code:

```
{
    $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund_$a[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
    $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund_$a[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
    $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund_$a[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
    }
```

so as `$a` is changed everytime the if statement is accessed, i could have a different set of these arrays for everytime the if statement is accessed, but php doesn't accept this and i wouldn't have a very good result, though if i can reach it i would be pleased.

But my goal is to get:

```
{
        $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund_1[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
        $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund_1[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
        $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund_1[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
        }
{
        $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund_2[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
        $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund_2[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
        $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund_2[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
        }
```

...

where the last number represents the array retrieved for the n-th time the if statement runned. Does someone have a tip for it?

Thanks in advance! Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

As asked, my real world terms is as follows:

I have a table from which i need to take all the data that is inside a given interval. BUT, there's a problem, my data is a sine function whose amplitude may change indefinite times (the data bank is entered by the user) and, when the amplitude goes inside that interval, i need to make some operations like getting the least value achieved while the data was inside that interval and some other parameters, for each interval separately, (That's why i created all those tables.) and count how many times it happpened.
So, in order to make one of the operations, i need an array with the data for each time the databank entered by the user goes in that interval (given by the limits of the create query.).

If i were not clear, just tell me please!

**EDIT 2**

Here's the image of part of the table i'm working with:
http://postimg.org/image/5vegnk043/

so, when the sine gets inside the interval i need, it can be seen by the L1_RMS column, who accuses it, so it's when i need to get the interval data until it gets outside the interval. But it may happens as many times as this table entered by the user brings it on and we need to bear in mind that i need all the intervals separately to deal with the data of each one.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine how creating an undefined number of tables in a relational database is the right way to solve any problem

Comment: Yikes..How is creating a new array every time different then accessing the data like `$array_forma_onda_fase3_afund[$a]`?

Comment: I'm really new at this, that was the way i figured out to solve another problem in getting some data. I don't know if this is the real problem, but i drop the tables after i place the information in php arrays.

Comment: @immulatin, hmm, i don't know if that's a good solution, because u are saying that 1 term of the array equals all the rows retrieved by the fetch. I think it wouldn't work. But please, feel free to correct me any time. as i said, i'm beginner at this. :) And i'll try that just as i reach home.

Comment: Why not create a single associative array, where the key is the name you were going to give the dynamically created array in your above example?

Comment: @GustavoxD can you take a step back and explain what you are trying to do in real world terms? I think you might have gone so far down the road of creating all these database tables and such that you are confusing the issue of what you are actually trying to do. Can you explain in terms of I have data X as an input and I am looking to output it as Y?

Comment: @MikeBrant, when u have some time, please, read my edit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GustavoxD I guess it would really help if you showed some sample data (both the data that exists in the table and what the user inputs).

Comment: @MikeBrant, please, see my edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics uh?

You can do what you wanted with the arrays, it's not pretty, but it's possible.
You can dynamically name your arrays with the _$a in the end, Variables variables, such as:

${"array_forma_onda_fase3_afund_" . $a}[] = "fisica é medo";

Comment: Hmm, that seems interesting. I'll try just as i arrive home. E nem me diga. hahah. Mas na verdade, é engenharia elétrica. :(